# Lightword Theme - only one menu item

Tags: themes, menus

Since I am pretty new to WP and the whole stuff i ran into a problem.
I am using the pretty-well known "Lightword" Theme. And today i've upgraded to the newest version. 
It's now possible to add/edit the menu items through the theme-settings. Although I like this very much I am not able to display more than one additional menu-item.

When I go to "wp-admin/nav-menus.php" I am able to select a menu item in a box (the english titel of the box is probably: "Position in theme") on the left-side. But I am only able to select one. 
So what can I do to show up all created menus?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to display multiple menu items, or multiple menus?

Each theme supports a certain number of menus. Your's may only support one menu, that is the menu position.

You create a menu to go there. From withing the menu creator interface you put all the items you want to appear on your menu. You can even nest items, to create children in your menu.

You assign that menu you have created to the position, depending how many your theme supports. Many only support one menu natively. You can only add one menu per position, but that one menu can have as many items as you like. You set up your top level items, and assign children by dragging the items below and slightly to the side of a parent item. For most themes, the children items will behave as dropdowns.

If you want to add more, you can code them in, or use a widget. WordPress comes with a custom menu widget which allows you to assign custom menus to it.

Comment: Well you're right. That was too simple. ;) Thanks for your answer I now got the difference between menu and menu-item. I misunderstood it.

Comment: Sure, glad to help!!